# How to get latitude & longitude onclick on google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to find the path between two locations on Google Maps which I have clicked.
So when I click anywhere on the map I want to get the latitude & longitude.
How can I do that?

Comment: check this blog explain all google maps tutorials `http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how much research you have done but there are tons of simple to follow tutorials to do what you are asking about.  I'm sure you have a specific goal you are trying to accomplish but you should take a look at this open source project I came across when I googled android gps services

http://code.google.com/p/gpslogger/

take a look through the source code in that project and I guarantee you will see how to do exactly what your asking.

I'm pretty sure you would use the android.location services so you could also google how to use those. But in order to see them in use you definitely should check out that link I posted above.